# Creating Replica of Account Object Fields in New And Edit button

Tags: lightning-experience

I have a requirement to Create vf page that overrides New and Edit buttons,i had used Hyperlink in error mesage.if enduser has duplicates,it should through error message in create and update.iam able to see link in error message,while creating new dupliucate record.but in update,that means edit on any record and then tried to save the record,error message is working fine but link can came.any clues,?!
need help,thanks in advance

Comment: If you wish to receive proper answer then share your code

Comment: account.addError('Error. Click <a href="' + URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()  + '">here</a>.', false);

Comment: Above error message is not displayed in vf page that ovveridden edit button of account,how to display error message in in vf page,that overrides edit button.